# how to check the type of a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I have the following code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class Name
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Name1
{
    int a;
    int b;
};


int main()
{

  Name1* name1;
  Name*  name;

  // trying to implement the following code:
  // check if name1 is of type of pointer Name1 then do someting
  // check if name is of type of pointer Name then do someting

}
```

how to check the type of pointer `name1`?

Name1 and Name are not inherited, the dynamic_cast can not be used, then how to check the type of a pointer?

Comment: The type is `Name1*`.... it's right there.

Comment: yes, I know, I mean how to check the type of the pointer using code?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the type is what you declared it as! Your two classes are completely unrelated, there is no relation between them at all.

Comment: Did you want something like this:
    template<typename T>
    void SomeFunction(T t)
    {
    #ifdef WIN32
       TRACE("%s\n", __FUNCSIG__);
    #else
       cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    #endif
    }

Comment: The type is `Name1*` dude,  I don't understand your questions.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like [`std::is_same<decltype(name), Name*>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking to templates (unrelated classes) or inheritance (related classes) instead what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think what they want is a way to output the *type* of a variable. For example in VB.NET a `.ToString()` can be used on a variable to get its type.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ: In standard C++, `typeid(var).name()` will do that, although the exact textual representation is implementation-defined.

Comment: Why would you want to check the type of something you declared?

Comment: this seems like an X-Y problem. what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Compile time differentiation:

You can use a template and its specialization:

```
template <class T>
bool isName(T *t) { return false; } // normal case returns false 
 
template <>
bool isName(Name *t) { return true; } // but for Name returns true
```

Then you can differentiate your code, for [example](http://ideone.com/1S84cJ):

```
Name *n; Name1 *n1;
cout << "(1): " << isName(n) << endl;
cout << "(2): " << isName(n1) << endl;
```

You can of course use `isName()` in conditions to process depending on the class of the object.

From a design perspective, if you have class-specific code, it may, however, be more interesting to wrap it in some templates and use the specialization demonstrated above, not for returning a Boolean, but doing what is to be done, for [example](http://ideone.com/dGpjQr):

```
template <class T>
void doMyStuff(T *t) {}  // in general do nothing 
 
template <>
void doMyStuff(Name *t) { cout << "do something with Name*"<< endl;}

template <> 
void doMyStuff(Name1 *t) { cout << "do something with Name1*"<<endl; }

...
doMyStuff(n);
doMyStuff(n1);
```

## Run time differentiation:

If you need to decide run time on an arbitrary pointer, you need dynamic **run-time type information**. The standard C++ has RTTI for that. But it requires at least one virtual function in the class. So, you can't just take any pointer (e.g. `void*`) and find out what data it points to! You need a pointer to a valid polymorphic class.

The clean way to do it would be to make `Name` and `Name1` both inherit from a technical common class with a virtual function:

```
class void {
    virtual void mv() {};
};
```

Then you can use `dynamic_cast` and the **[`<typeinfo>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/)** to work with the type of your object, and easily use pointers to the base object:

```
void f(void *p){
    cout << "f("<<p<<"):" << typeid(*p).name() << endl;
}
```

You can then call this function by providing it a pointer to the derived classes:

```
Name *n=new Name;
Name1 *n1=new Name1;
f(n);   // no risk here, it's automatic conversion to base type 
f(n1);
```

Note that for a better design, you can also embed any class-specific behavior in a virtual function, that is specialized for each derived type. But then it's the start of a solid class design, and your assumption was: unrelated classes.

A more error-prone approach is to keep each of these classes independent but making sure that each has at least one virtual function, in order to ensure that they are polymorphic and contain RTTI information.

You could then use the dangerous `reinterpret_cast` and use access to RTTI information.  [This code](http://ideone.com/fstcAW) demonstrate the principle:

```
f(reinterpret_cast<vvoid*>(n)); 
f(reinterpret_cast<vvoid*>(n1));
```

It seems to work.  However, if by accident you'd cast a class that has no virtual function, your code would compile without warnings, but it would awfully stumble at execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost: boost/type_index.hpp. Below you can find code:

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

struct TName
{

};

struct TName1
{

};

int main()
{
    TName* name;
    cout << "param = " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(name)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

    if (type_id_with_cvr<decltype(name)>().pretty_name() == "TName*")
    {
        std::cout << "Variant 1\n";
    }

    TName1* name1;
    if (type_id_with_cvr<decltype(name1)>().pretty_name() == "TName1*")
    {
        std::cout << "Variant 2\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

param = TName*

Variant 1

Variant 2

Answer (score -2):

You can use typeid for this:

```
string typeToFind == "Name1 *";
if(typeToFind.compare(typeid(Name1).name()) == 0) {
    //Your code
}
```

It may not be pretty, but it does the trick.

Comment: No, it does not. The result of `name` is implementation-defined!

Comment: P.S.: Why compare two `std::string` objects like this when there is `operator==`?

Comment: Yeah good point. name is definitely implementation specific. I used the compare since I'm used to getting a char * back from name. Can't do a == between a string and a char* IIRC.

Comment: You can use `operator==` with `char*`, if the other operand is a `std::string`.